# PhonegapBuild Google Admob and Googlemaps plugins conflict

Tags: admob, google-maps-android-api-2, phonegap-build

I have been searching online for a solution for this problem but i haven ́t found any related topics. What i am trying to do is compile with PGB cli5.2 using 2 Google plugins Admob and Googlemaps:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-armsoft-googlemaps" source="npm">
<param name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="MyKey" />
<param name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="MyKey" />
</gap:plugin>
```

and i get the following error:

"Error - Two of the plugins in your app are incompatible as they both add a file with the same name. View logs to find which plugins are causing this issue. - You can fix this here"

Does anyone have an idea of whats causing it or had the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of cordova-plugin-admob. I've submitted an issue to other plugin in order to solve this issue: https://github.com/roberthovhannisyan/cordova-plugin-google-play-services/issues/1